# Modifying imported bootstrap code within html file

Tags: html, css, django

I am making a django web application where I have `base.html` and `base_bootstrap.html` files.  My `base_bootstrap.html` file contains the following two lines to use bootstrap CSS:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
.
.
.
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there a way for me to modify the following css in order to change the `#999` into a `#` without creating a separate css file?

```
pre {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always override `external css` by using either **internal css** on the page or the **inline css** specifically to the HTML element.

Example:

```
.card
{
  margin:5px;
  padding:25px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  background:#ddd;
}
.card{
  border:2px solid #f00;
}

<div class="card"></div>
```

You can also use `!important` to override any css with the HTML element.

*Example:* `border:2px solid black !important;`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wdeyp017/)**

Refer to: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

**Use Internal CSS**

You can override the color code by declaring it again in your HTML page again.

```
pre {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    page-break-inside: avoid
}
pre {
    border-color:#878;
}
```

Your pre tag have now a border-color at #878.

But, if you can change the nativ color code, change him.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the the SASS version and modify the parts you want or include a custom file with modifications / extra styles you want, then rebuild bootstrap with the gem installed or create your own Grunt/Gulp script to build the SASS to CSS.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

BS is originally built in LESS which would work too.